# How to run the same sampler in Jmeter until I get specific result in response data Json

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, web-api-testing

I want to run the same sampler until I get `polling_status": "success",` it will be inprogess for some time after few sec will get success ststus. Until the status changes to success I want to run the same sampler. Once the status change I want to move to next sampler. How can I achive this in Jmeter?

I have highlighted it which value will change

```
{
    "data": {
        "trip_id": "003",
        "selection_id": "d80acc5311",
        "polling_start_time": "2023-06-07 14:11:11.841000",
        "leg_info": [
            {
                "selection_status": 1,
                "user": "8"
            }
        ],
        
    *"polling_status": "inprogress",*

        "selection_status": 0,
        "polling_starts": true
    },
    "selection_id": "e8550872-c3dd-4f5e-827b-68d80acc5311",
    "status": "success",
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put your request under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) and use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${status}" != "success",)}
   ```

   [image]
2. Add [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request and configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. That's it, the While Controller will run the request until `polling_status` attribute value is not `success`, once it becomes `success` it will exit the loop and proceed to the next Samplers or Controllers. Something like:

   [image]

Comment: Works fine exactly how I wanted. Thanks for the help